# Javascript client side tweet fetch capabilities

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, twitter, client-side

I'm looking for ways to avoid using a ruby library for [fetching tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/), and processing the returned JSON. My goal is simply to display tweets from a specific account, in html. Ideally I would use AJAX to periodically update the div, with the latest tweets.

All of this can easily be accomplished using ruby's [twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/). However I am working within the context of a framework and I'd like to avoid creating a controller and resource to hit.

So the solution I'm exploring are Client Side solutions. I am unaware as to the best practices for this, and if there are any common library's used. Do you have any experience with this or resources you could point me towards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [Twitter JSONP API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery on the client, you could try using this: http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/